# Accessing resources showing my console in Angular 8

Tags: angular

In trying to access my data I’m receiving in the console and it keeps returning blank values.
Where I am going wrong here!

home.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of googleData | keyvalue">
      <h3>Title :{{ item.title }}</h3>
    </div>
```

home.component.ts

```
public googleData:any;

  searchData(){ 
      return this.googleService.getGoogle().subscribe(x =>{
        this.googleData= x.items;
        console.log(this.googleData)
       }, error => {
         console.log(error)
       })
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: what is data in googleData

Comment: `googleData` seems to be a simple array of objects. Try without `keyvalue` pipe.

Comment: please I have updated my code @Giannis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use "keyvalue" to display your title.

Angular say for keyvaluePipe :

> Transforms Object or Map into an array of key value pairs.

So, it's not useful in your code here.